# Can I include the table name in the result of an SQL query?

Tags: sql

If I have two tables:

```
Actor:
ID | Name
1  : Patrick
3  : Emma
7  : Vanessa

Singer:
ID | Name
4  : Will
5  : Madonna
13 : Emma
```

Can I generate the following table from an SQL query, which contains the table name each record came from?

```
ID | Career | Name
1  : Actor  : Patrick
3  : Actor  : Emma
4  : Singer : Will
5  : Singer : Madonna
7  : Actor  : Emma
13 : Singer : Emma
```

I'm assuming the ID column items are unique across the two tables, but not the names.

Comment: Bad DB design or bad sample. The same person can be an actor and a singer.

Comment: Tell that to the people on broadway

Comment: It would appear that no-one has actually answered the question though. None of the responses use the *table name*, preferring instead to use constants that happen to be the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
select ID, 'Actor' as Career, Name from Actor
union all
select ID, 'Singer' as Career, Name from Singer
```

Or something along these lines.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but I note that it doesn't actually answer the question. The *table name* does not appear in the result, rather there is a constant that happens to be the same. I'm assuming my actual question can't be answered in SQL.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT ID, 'Actor' AS Career, Name FROM Actor
UNION
SELECT ID, 'Singer' AS Career, Name FROM Singer
```

Comment: It's a nitpick, but you should use UNION ALL if you don't need duplicates removed.

Comment: It's not a nitpick. You are exactly right. If there were a unique constraint on (Id, Name) UNION ALL would effectively yield the same result as UNION, but only faster. But honestly I wouldn't care for duplicate records in this case.

Answer (score 4):

OK, two people beat me to the sample query I was posting.

But, I think the better answer to your root question is, if "Career" is a relevant attribute in your data, and the IDs are expected to be unique, why not have one table in which Career is an actual column?

Comment: +1 While others, as me (already deleted), were answered as asked, this one is the best answer, actually.

Comment: Normalization is for suckers :p This is the eternal tradeoff between answering the question, or solving his problem :)

Comment: It's part of a larger problem, reduced for the purposes of asking a question on SO. I'm trying to figure out a minimally disruptive way of adding a minor feature.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the table names you're querying *from* you can simply include the table name as a literal value in the result set:

```
SELECT ID, 'Actor', Name FROM Actor
  UNION SELECT ID, 'Singer', Name FROM Singer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select id, 'Actor' as Career, Name
from Actor
union
select id, 'Singer' as Career, Name
from Singer
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal either but it does answer your question assuming the database has only two tables.

```
DECLARE @t1 nvarchar(10) = (SELECT top 1 TABLE_NAME
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
DECLARE @t2 nvarchar(10) = (SELECT top 1 TABLE_NAME
                            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                            WHERE NOT TABLE_NAME = @t1)

DECLARE @SQLcommand nvarchar(400)

SET @SQLcommand = 'select ID, '+ @t1 +' as Career, Name from ' + @t1 +
                  ' union all select ID, '+ @t2 +' as Career, Name from ' +@t2

EXEC(@SQLcommand)
```

I agree with above that the design really does need to get looked at for you to need this.